# MIME base64 encode wide characters

Tags: perl, mime

I use MIME::Base64 to encode some strings to safely pass over a URL 
But there are time where the code breaks due to wide characters

How can I safely encode wide characters, I need not use MIME::Base64 , any lightweight encoding will work for me

```
use MIME::Base64;
print  MIME::Base64::encode_base64("\x{2019}s text");
print "\nBye\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/MIME::Base64), `encode_base64` accepts *bytes* as the argument. To get bytes from a string, encode it:

```
use Encode;

print  MIME::Base64::encode_base64(encode('utf-8', "\x{2019}s text"));
```

Don't forget to `decode` back on the receiving side!

Comment: Remembering that the receiving code must also *decode* the byte string after it has decoded the Base 64 data.

Comment: @Borodin: I forgot to mention it, updated now. Thanks for a reminder.

Comment: But that will mean a double encode everytime , even if there is no wide character

Comment: @Ram: Moreover, for strings without a wide char, `encode` doesn't change anything, so what?

Comment: I guess I will do that , but is there a simpler encode algorithm